How do I disable tab switching animation?
I use extjs 6.6.0. There is a tab view:
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        }
    ]
});

Actually, this example is located at the link here: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.tab.Panel.html#configs
Tell me how to disable tab animation. Need a tough adventure. I pressed it and it switched over. I can't figure out how to do this
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    hideMode : 'clip',
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        }
    ]
});

I thought it was done somehow using hideMode : 'clip'. But having used it, I understand that this is not the case. Either I'm doing something wrong.
Please help me turn off the animation.

What you are looking for is the layout:
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    height  : 300,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    layout: {
        type: 'card',
        animation: null
        /*
        Possible values for animation are null or Object
            { type: 'fade' }
        Possilbe values for type are
            // 'cover' 'cube' 'fade' 'flip' 'pop' 'reveal' 'scroll' 'slide'
        */
    },

    items: [
        { title: 'Home', iconCls: 'home', html: 'Home Screen' },
        { title: 'Contact', iconCls: 'user', html: 'Contact Screen' }
    ]
});

